# How to use DataBindings with RxJava?

Tags: android, rx-java, android-databinding

I am trying to combine `dataBinding` with `RxJava` so that it looks something like that:

layout.xml:

```
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
        //...
        app:rxClick="@{viewModel.onTap}">
    <TextView
            //...
            android:text="@{viewModel.title}"
    </TextView>
    //...
```

ViewModel:

```
class ViewModel {
    val title = PublishSubject.create<String>()
    val onTap = PublishSubject.create<Void>()
    //...
}
```

But I cannot find an easy way to make it like that.

One of the things I found while researching is `ObservableField` and `LiveData` which is included in the `dataBinding` library. And I do not think it is a good solution because `rxJava` is much more sophisticated and `ObservableField` does not seem to be compatible with `rxJava`.

Another thing I found is this library https://github.com/ArthurVimond/RxBindingAdapters which kind of suits the case. But it does not work, failing with the error while compiling:

```
e: [kapt] An exception occurred: android.databinding.tool.util.LoggedErrorException: Found data binding errors.
****/ data binding error ****msg:cannot find type element for io.reactivex.subjects.Subject
```

Is there another option I missed? Any suggestions?